# Obstructions to maximal number of independent constants of motion in a given symplectic manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology

Given a compact symplectic manifold $(X, \omega)$, are there any invariants (topological or easily computable geometric/analytic ones) which give an estimate of the maximal number of independent constants of motions in $(X, \omega)$?

More precisely, we would like to find a reasonable bound on a number $k \in \mathbb{N}$, which is the maximal number such that there are $k$ generically linearly independent functions $f_1, \ldots, f_k$ (i.e. $df_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge df_k \neq 0$ generically), which Poisson commute with respect to $\omega$.

Trivially, we have $1 \leq k \leq n$, where $\dim X = 2n$. Moreover, if $k = n$, then by Liouville-Arnold theorem the manifold $X$ admits a (Lagrangian) torus fibrations away from the singular points, which is a non-trivial topological obstruction (I suppose; is it by the way correct?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any symplectic 2n-dimensional
manifold admits a systems of Poisson-commuting  functions $f_1,..,f_n$ whose differentials are linearly independent on an open subset of full measure.

The result is proven in the book    ''Symplectic geometry" of A.T. Fomenko. The initial russian  version and  its  engish translation    have different paging;   in the english version you should start with the page   145.

The proof is as follows: one first constructs such functions $f_1,...,f_n$ on  the standard symplectic space such that the  support of  each  function
$f_i$ is the same standard 1-ball
and then  fills the manifolds  by such balls, properly scaled.

Of course the singularities of such system are nasty and form a multidimentional  Cantor-type set